# Jquery hover triggers "mouse leave" without cursor leaving

Tags: jquery, hover

I have a button `li` with a nested `input`. I added hover function with jQuery to the `li` element. It works fine except when I hover in and out of the `li` button really quickly, the `mouseenter` won't trigger and instead only `mouseleave` triggers, even when still hovering on the element.

I know the problem is caused by the timer, but I can't figure out how to set it up to work as intended.

```
$(document).ready(function() {    
  $('.topMenu__item--button').hover(function () {
    var hoverTimeout;
    clearTimeout(hoverTimeout);
    $(this).addClass('topMenu__item--button--hover');
  }, function() {
    var $self = $(this);
    hoverTimeout = setTimeout(function() {
      $self.removeClass('topMenu__item--button--hover');
    }, 500);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to move the `hoverTimeout` declaration to be in scope of both functions:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var hoverTimeout;

  $('.topMenu__item--button').hover(function() {
    clearTimeout(hoverTimeout);
    $(this).addClass('topMenu__item--button--hover');
  }, function() {
    var $self = $(this);
    hoverTimeout = setTimeout(function() {
      $self.removeClass('topMenu__item--button--hover');
    }, 500);
  });
});
```

You should also note that it would be better practice to put this hover behaviour in to CSS, as it performs much better than JS.

Comment: Thank you amazing man, that solved it! And also thanks for the advice to put it all into css, I'll definitely consider it!